# How to set dynamic limit in angular flex slider?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slider, flexslider

I am use angular flexslider.

Here are link

https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider.

I want to set dynamic limit for view slides items.
I am set static limit but its not worked can you give me
helpful suggestion how to set slides Items limit.

Here is my flex slider code:

```html
<flex-slider slider-id="carousel" flex-slide="department in data.departments track by $index" animation="slide"
             animation-loop="false" item-width="277" slidesItems="1" item-margin="1" keyboard="false"
             as-nav-for="#slider" slideshow="false" minItems= "1"   control-nav="false" >
```

Comment: By `dynamic limit`, do you mean to set the attribute `slidesItems`'s value dynamically?

Comment: I can't find a property `slidesItems` only `minItems` and `maxItems` - https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider#properties